# Rails Tutorial unexpected Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm currently going through the awesome Rails Tutorial, and after I did a git reset to return to a previous commit, something broke to my database and all of a sudden I get 5 failures when I run rspec.

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController Get 'show' should be successfull
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<#<Class:0xaadc884>:0xaad9990>
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__463664834_89565070__435144589'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController Get 'show' should find the right user
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<#<Class:0xaadc884>:0xa820ca8>
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__463664834_89565070__435144589'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) UsersController Get 'show' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<#<Class:0xaadc884>:0x9f0e7b4>
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__463664834_89565070__435144589'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) UsersController Get 'show' should include the user's name
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<#<Class:0xaadc884>:0xb930cc8>
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__463664834_89565070__435144589'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) UsersController Get 'show' should have a profile image
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<#<Class:0xaadc884>:0xb9ade94>
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__463664834_89565070__435144589'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm sure this easy to fix, but I honestly dont know where to even look at. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are calling `gravatar_for`which is unknown, line 5 of: `./app/views/users/show.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
 undefined method `gravatar_for' for #<#<Class:0xaadc884>:0xb9ade94>
```

You need to make sure the gravatar is specificed in your profile model.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `gravatar_for`, which is unknown, line 5 of: `./app/views/users/show.html.erb`

Even if this is already an answer, please provide details so that we fix it.

I'm pretty sure you forgot to add the method to your `User` model.